# Split xpath with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, xpath

I use php and I need to split a string (xpath) with regular expression.
I need just one regex to split to following "inputs". I hope someone can help me.

---

**Input:**
/path/to/node/test

**Output:**

```
$result = array(
    "path",
    "to",
    "node",
    "test",
);
```

---

**Input:**
/path/to[sub="string" AND sub2="string2"]/node/test

**Output:**

```
$result = array(
    'path',
    'to[sub="string" AND sub2="string2"]',
    'node',
    'test',
);
```

---

**Input:**
/path/to[sub/path/to="string"]/node/test

**Output:**

```
$result = array(
    'path',
    'to[sub/path/to="string"]',
    'node',
    'test',
);
```

Thanks before!

Best regards
Sascha

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use `explode`

```
$str = explode('/',yourString)
```

Or if you have inner `/` onnly inside `[]` which you want to ignore you can try the following regex:

```
preg_match_all("/\[(?:[^\[\]]|(?R))+\]|[^\[\]\/]+/", $input, $matches);
```

Example:

```
$input = '/path/to[sub/path/to="string"]/node/test';
preg_match_all("/\[(?:[^\[\]]|(?R))+\]|[^\[\]\/]+/", $input, $matches);
var_dump($input);
var_dump($matches); //this will give you expected output
```

Explanation:

We're capturing 2 types here:

1. `/\[(?:[^\[\]]|(?R))+\]` matches anything between square brackets recursively
2. `[^\[\]\/]+` matches any char-sequence not consisting of `[` `]`

Comment: @MikeCAT try the alternative regex

Comment: WIth the new regex, `"to"` and `"[sub/path/to="string"]"` are splitted, but in the exanple they aren't. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JEQfPQEKgJfzLhHt